# How to count all queries per hostgroup in ProxySQL?

Tags: proxysql

Are there any statistics available in ProxySQL that show the total count per hostgroup (or per server)?

`SELECT rule_id, hits, destination_hostgroup FROM mysql_query_rules NATURAL JOIN stats_mysql_query_rules;` does show statistics per rule, but it does not provide information on how many queries are actually sent to each hostgroup. Additionally, the `Questions` metric from `stats_mysql_global` only shows the total number of statements executed, without distinguishing between hosts or hostgroups.

`SELECT hostgroup, COUNT(*) AS query_count FROM stats_mysql_query_digest GROUP BY hostgroup;` does not seem to display the total count. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It appears that this query calculates a count per hostgroup using `SELECT hostgroup, SUM(count_star) AS num_queries FROM stats.stats_mysql_query_digest GROUP BY hostgroup;` where it sums the 'count_star' column instead of counting individual rows. However, the issue is that it doesn't precisely match `Questions` count from `SELECT Variable_Value FROM stats.stats_mysql_global WHERE Variable_Name = 'Questions';`.